# How to use kubectl debug to check the running processes of an existing container in a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to see details `ps aux` of one particular process in a container. I have a deployment with one container in it. The deployment has

```yaml
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: true
```

In order to see the processes running in the container I tried to launch a temporary new container in the same space as the existing one. This new container should have access to same processes and resources (this is what I believe and wanted to test). The command I use is

```bash
kubectl debug pod-name -c my-new-container --image=busybox -it -- sh
```

When I ran it I got a warning,
**"container busybox: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root"**

After this message prompt does not return. It hangs.

Is it because of the **runAsNonRoot**? If it is what is the workaround?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Try passing sleep command (`sh -c sleep 3600`) to debug pod, then `exec` into that container and then try running ps aux.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because of the runAsNonRoot? If it is what is the workaround?

Correct. The Pod's security context disallows running containers as root, while your debugger image wants to run as root by default.

The workaround is to make the ephemeral container also run as non-root. You can either find an image that already has a `USER` instruction in it or quickly build your own:

```
$ docker build -t registry/non-root-alpine -<<EOF
FROM alpine

USER 1000
EOF

$ docker push registry/non-root-alpine

$ kubectl debug -it --image registry/non-root-alpine -c debugger-123 <pod>
```

Alternatively, you can create an ephemeral container directly (via an API call), configuring its security context with a proper UID. In this case, you won't need to look for a special "non-root" image:

```
kubectl proxy &

curl -Lvk localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/<pod>/ephemeralcontainers \
  -XPATCH \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json' \
  -d '
{
    "spec":
    {
        "ephemeralContainers":
        [
            {
                "name": "debugger-123",
                "command": ["sh"],
                "image": "alpine",
                "stdin": true,
                "tty": true,
                "securityContext": {"runAsNonRoot": true, "runAsUser": 101}
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

After that, you will need to use either `kubectl attach` or `kubectl exec`:

```
kubectl exec -it -c debugger-123 <pod> -- sh
```

This is a very interesting problem, and I even prepared [an online playground](https://labs.iximiuz.com/challenges/kubernetes-signal-non-root-container) to demonstrate it and the potential solutions.